# Is there any reason to use a different app other than iMovie to record video via webcam of a long lecture I'll be attending?

Tags: mac, video, recording, webcam

Is there any reason to use a different app other than iMovie to record video via webcam of a long lecture I'll be attending?  If so, what is that app and why?  Just as a note, I don't plan to do any kind of editing of the video, just recording only.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!  I'm going to continue researching this question right now.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't have a built-in or iSight camera, iMovie might not detect it. In my case I have a logitech Camera and iMovie doesn't find it, but QuickTime Pro will let me record.